# how to find sin13° cos13° tan13° cot13° with trigonometric circle.

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I have problem finding sin(13°) cos(13°) tan(13°) cot(13°)with trigonometric circle. I have to draw the circle with a triangle on it but I can't get the right thing.

Comment: You need to be a bit clearer, I guess

Comment: With the unit circle

Comment: $\tan$ and $\cot$ cancel and you may know that $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$.

Comment: If you understood Hagen von Eitzen's remark, the only thing left is the computation of sin(26°) / 2. Can you take from here ?

Comment: I think finding the value of $\sin 26^\circ$ from a unit circle is the difficult part of all.

Comment: I have been a teacher and I suppose they are allowed to draw an angle into the unit circle, intersect it with the circle and then read the length of the corresponding lines in the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, maybe it will help you:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle

Comment: I read it and watch some videos but I don't know with this homework.

Comment: What is the context (which grade are you in? So we know what kind of means you may use)

Comment: The second year in high school

Comment: Then this means probably you may solve this by drawing the unit circle and respective triangles into it. See wikipedia link above.

Comment: Like we have for example sin90°=1 ,I have to find sin13°

Comment: In order to find sin13° draw the above mentioned unit circle. Name the center M. Draw a triangle as follows: a horizontal line from the center M to the right. Call the intersection of that line and the circle A. Draw an angle of 13° in the center, i.e. a line starting at M, going upwards at 13°. Call the intersection with the circle B. In the triangle MAB find the hight from B to AM. The length of that divided by the radius of the unit circle is sin13°.

Comment: I get 1 but the result has to be 0.225

Comment: You might have divided the wrong lengths. Be sure to determine the hight of that triangle and divide it by the hypothenuse.

Comment: Can you do this,you will help me a lot.

Comment: Actually, I shouldn't really be doing your homework. Moreover it's hard to explain more exact just by writing. Maybe someone close to you can help you with the text I wrote.